# How to handle small files problem in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

My current flow in Nifi is like

```
ListHDFS->FetchHDFS->SplitText->JoltransformJSon->PUTHBaseJSON.
```

Hourly input JSON files would be max of 10GB.
Single file size would be 80 -100MB.

Splittext & JoltTransform -> transform the text and sent it as 4KB files . Hence the hourly job is taking 50 to 1.20 minutest to complete the flow . How can I make this faster. What would be the best flow to handle the use case.

Have tried to use Mergecontent , didnt worked out well .

Thanks All

Answer (score 3):

You can use **MergeRecord processor** After **JoltTransfromJson Processor** and

keep your **maximum number of records** to make flowfile eligible to merge into single flowfile.

Use **Max Bin Age** property as wildcard to **force eligible the bin to be Merged**.

Then use record oriented processor for HBase i.e **PutHBaseRecord** processor and configure your **Record Reader controller service(JsonTree Reader)** to read the **incoming flowfile** and tune the `Batch size` property value to get maximum performance.

By using this process we are processing chunks of records which eventually increase the performance of storing data into HBase.

**Flow:**

```
ListHDFS->FetchHDFS->SplitText->JoltransformJSon->MergeRecord ->PUTHBaseRecord
```

Refer to these links for [Merge Record configs](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/64337/apache-nifi-merge-content.html) and [Record Reader configs](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi)